# Accessing child element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Assuming I have this HTML structure:

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li>
       <div></div>
       <div>
          <div></div>
          <div>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How would I, using jQuery, go about accessing "Text"? I know I need to use something like $('a').text(), but my hangup lies in not knowing how to get down to that level when I only know the class of the UL at the top. I've tried using variations of .children() but I'm not quite sure how to traverse down that far.

**Please assume that I cannot change any of the original HTML markup.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the only anchor inside `ul.menu`? Then simply `$("ul.menu a")`.

Comment: `$('ul.menu a')`, `$('ul').find('a')`.

Comment: Define what elements you want to match. Is it only anchors within `ul.menu`?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: If the tag you know is a `ul` then the content *must* be in an `li` element, so: `$('ul.menu li a')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should handle it

```
$('.menu a').text();
```

edit: to include code for edited question

here is how to loop through all links in `.menu`

```
$('.menu a').each(function(){

   alert(  $(this).text() );
});
```

Comment: Duh, thank you. I managed to figure how to loop through it on my own - something I've done quite a few times before. Here's to 4:30 pm on friday afternoon...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that would even work if there are more links in the other divs:

```
$('.menu li div:eq(1) div:eq(1) a').text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/utJsu/

Answer (score 0):

You could also give the anchor tag a specific class or id, then use that class or id to select it.

HTML

```
<a class="menu-link" href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('.menu-link').text();
```

The benefit of using a unique class as a selector is that if you have other anchor tags under the menu, you will only affect the ones that have the given class.

The other link with no class will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have several a inside of .menu you can use each

```
$('.menu a').each(function(){$(this).text(); // gives you the text of each a});
```